# Power Rangers-style show where the protagonists could transform into robots using special cards

Tags: story-identification

I used to watch a show on Cartoon Network (2011-2012) that was like Power Rangers. It was a live-action show, not a cartoon, and probably Japanese in origin.

The heroes of the show (several men and a woman) used special cards to transfer into robots. They could also make a huge robot by themselves.

Comment: I'm glad you took the advice you were given and reposted this here from Movies.SE, but at the same time, I still feel as though this isn't going to be enough information to go on. Is there anything else you remember about this show? Anything at all?

Comment: Can you remember when you watched this? What did the heroes fight? Was it a story per season or episode style show? Can you remember any of the plot? If you remember anything else please [edit] that detail into the question.

Comment: I watched that show about 6/7 years ago...

Comment: there are several hero and heroine who have individual card and work as team for defending the villain.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 4):

I know this one! VR Troopers. Very similar to Power Rangers. Here is a clip of the cards you mention.

Comment: I was going to suggest [Beetleborgs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DWymzTNSFUQ) but this is a better fit.

Comment: not any of these...these are very old...but the show i am talking was around 2011/12

Answer (score 0):

You may be thinking of *[Genseishin Justirisers](https://gransazer.fandom.com/wiki/GenSeiShin_JustiRisers)*, a 2004-2005 series which Cartoon Network broadcast dubbed in English, although I haven't found any firm data on in which years, or in which locations, they did so.

> The JustiRisers are three chosen humans who are granted the use of the mysterious JustiPower, the "Earth's will" that was discovered by the Riserian Noulan who utilized it to seal away Kaiser Hades long ago. Each is based on a different Chinese legend. Each one is equipped with an In-Loader that allows them to summon a high-powered suit of armor that transforms them into a JustiRiser. The transformation call is "Souchaku!" ("Equip!"). The In-Loader also acts as a communications device between the three JustiRisers.

The "In-Loader" is a bit larger than a card, but I could see it having that description:

[image: Shouta Date brandishing his In-Loader]

[image: CN image for the show]

The giant robot they would merge into was the "Giant Riser Shirogane".

[image: Giant Riser Shirogane]